# Types where Comments are allowed (or not) in Review Audits

Tags: support, comment, review-audit

My [recently failed review audit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/941208) got me to wondering which review audit types allow commenting and which don't allow them but advise you of this.

If you do a volume of reviews, you've probably seen cases where the attempt to post a Comment results in a red box popping up to inform you that "this is a review audit".

The case linked above is a case of First Posts.  The actual post is *not* a first post by any means, but the notation used in taking a "limit without l'Hopital" was quite laconic.  Assuming a true first post I wrote a Comment encouraging the user to (a) incorporate limit notation and (b) give a justification for the steps where a limit is taken.

It seems to me that Comments (of a constructive kind) have a non-pejorative sense on First Posts (compared to downvoting or flagging).

I wonder if [the revisions to disabling commenting on review audits](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23007/posting-comments-from-review-queues-has-become-error-prone) have been applied selectively by design, or if perhaps this is logical branch that got overlooked in making the changes.

**Update:**  I surmise from this [additional datapoint](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/941474) that review audits for Late Answers also allow Comments to be posted, apparently with the logic that commenting on a "bad" (i.e. previously removed) post gets a passing "grade".