# Is it enough to only comment for a First Question review?

Tags: discussion, support, review

I recently reviewed [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2884381/) question in the First Questions queue. I decided that the post needed more information and/or context, and commented nudging the new user in that direction. I then marked that I was done and monitored the post for further activity.

Was this the right thing to do, or should I have waited to see what the new user's response was to my comment? The review system allows a comment to serve as the review "action," but not monitoring the question after just a comment felt like an underwhelming response.

(Aside: No response came after some waiting, so I posted an answer with substantial hints.)

Comment: Yes, that is more than enough.  However the audits for the First Posts review queue are a little peculiar in how leaving a comment is treated.  [See here for my observations.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27768/types-where-comments-are-allowed-or-not-in-review-audits)

Comment: Aside: keep in mind you're not graded on how many users you interact with come away with answers. Answer questions because you think it's appropriate to answer them (and have the interest to do so) -- never feel compelled to answer something you think would be inappropriate simply because a user isn't responsive.